# How to call the method that returns Task<T> in a boolean return method

Tags: c#, xamarin, asynchronous

```
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    Task<TurnaResponse> RegisterUser(User user);

    Task<TurnaResponse> LoginUser(string email, string password);

    Task<TurnaResponse> ResetPassword(string userId, string password);

    Task<TurnaResponse> ForgotPassword(string email);

    Task<TurnaResponse> ProcessSession(string userId);

    bool IsUserAuthenticated();
}

public async Task<TurnaResponse> ProcessSession(string userId)
{
    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(ApiConstants.BaseApiUrl)
    {
        Path = ApiConstants.ProcessSessionEndpoint
    };

    var query = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
    query["userId"] = userId;
    builder.Query = query.ToString();

    var result = await _genericRepository.GetAsync<TurnaResponse>(builder.ToString(), "");
    result.Data = result.Data != null
        ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(result.Data.ToString()) : result.Data;

    _sessionResponse = (TurnaResponse)result;

    return result;
}
```

How can I call the ProcessSession method below to get the response object in IsAuthenticated method that returns boolean ?

```
public bool IsUserAuthenticated()
{
    var result = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_settingsService.UserIdSetting);

    if (result)
    {
        ProcessSession(_settingsService.UserIdSetting);

        result = _sessionResponse.Status;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You may turn it into async method as suggested in the answer below or call Sync-over-Async (that will freeze the current Thread until the method will return result). `_sessionResponse = ProcessSession(_settingsService.UserIdSetting).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: I tried this one but after it calls and takes the response from API method it does not bring to the xamarin code. I suppose the async methods cause confusion.

Comment: Maybe it cause a deadlock. Use the answer then.

Answer (score 5):

use async/await

```
public async Task<bool> IsUserAuthenticated()
{
    var result = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_settingsService.UserIdSetting);

    if (result)
    {
        var _sessionResponse = await ProcessSession(_settingsService.UserIdSetting);

        result = _sessionResponse.Status;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to call the asynchronous method from the synchronous method you can have a look at this thread [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c) . There is much explanation about the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid reusing the non-descriptive `bool` variable `result` to mean different things in different contexts.

```
public async Task<bool> IsUserAuthenticatedAsync()
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_settingsService.UserIdSetting)) return false;
    var sessionResponse = await ProcessSessionAsync(_settingsService.UserIdSetting);
    return sessionResponse.Status; // Assuming Status is a boolean property
}
```

I added the `Async` suffix to comply with the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types). I also removed the underscore prefix from the local variable `_sessionResponse` for [similar reasons](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md).

Answer (score -1):

```
use following code


public async Task<bool> IsUserAuthenticated()
{
    var userId= _settingsService.UserIdSetting;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)) 
    {
        var _sessionResponse = await ProcessSession(userId);
        result = _sessionResponse.Status;
    }
    return result;
}
```